# Not able to use two jar simultaneously?

Tags: android

I am not able to use these two jar file simultaneously in my project but i want both of these to work with:-

1.asmack-android-7.jar
2.smack-core-4.0.3.jar

Is there any other solution to use these jar simultaneously..

Thanks..

Comment: did you put the jars inside lib folder and added them in build path?

Comment: post your error log here...

Comment: Use any one of the two libraries. Use asmack for android.

Comment: Yes i put those into lib folder and also added in build path but still error in classes.

Comment: @Mahesh if we use one then there is error for classes.

Comment: For which classes? Be more specific and share some codes.

Comment: import org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException.NoResponseException;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException.NotConnectedException;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPException;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPException.XMPPErrorException;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Message;

Comment: for the above classes we have to import smack cor and for XMPP connection and presence classes need the asmack library..